# Which Linux distribution is more suitable for the Node.js web server

Tags: linux, node.js, webserver

I create a web server with Node.js. I'm using the Express framework. The database is MongoDB.

I want to host web server on a Linux machine. I don't know how to make the decision between the different Linux distributions, such as Debian, Unbuntu or RedHat.

My questions are:

1. What is the main difference of the different distributions?
2. Which factors should I take into account?
3. Which one is better for my requirement?

Comment: If you're going to manage it yourself, use whatever you're familiar with. It will save you lots of time.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Thank you. I have more experience on Debian. I want to know more pros/cons before making the final decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the main difference of the different distributions?

- Nothing. (As long as running node.js is the only concern)

Which factors should I take into account?

- Whether any unresolved issues are yet to be addressed by node.js.

Which one is better for my requirement?

- I would consider Ubuntu, as it's popular & bugs are addressed faster due to shorter release cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it in **Debian. Rock solid**!

In your case it also complies with the clever tip that Joachim Isaksson gave you - `use whatever you're familiar with`.